# Ayuda no puedo convertir un string con formato JSON a JSONArray en android

Tags: android, c#, webservice, webapi, jsonarray

hola soy nuevo en android studio estoy tratando de convertir us string con formato json en un objeto JSONArray en android studio pero tengo el siguiente error:

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"cve_prod":"ASPM1
>   ","descripcion":"ASP. JACTO PJH DE 20 LTS                ","activo":" 
>   ","umed":"PZA 
>   ","l1":"956.34","l3":"956.34","l2":"921.69","l4":"893.20"},{"cve_prod":"ASPM2
>   ","descripcion":"ASP.JACTO PJ PLUS18LTS                  ","activo":" 
>   ","umed":"PZA 
>   ","l1":"874.35","l3":"862.29","l2":"844.20","l4":"804.00"}

esta es mi funcion en c# es una webapi que codifica un datatable a json con la libreria de newtonsoft.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("GetProductsPrices")]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public String GetProductsPrices()
    {
        ProductsModel productsModel = new ProductsModel();

       string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productsModel.GetDataTableProducts());
       return json;    
    }
```

el resultado de la peticion se mira de la siguiente manera lo cual segun mi experiencia es un JSONArray valido

```
[{"cve_prod":"ASPM1 ","desc_prod":"ASP. JACTO PJH DE 20 LTS ","desc1":" ","uni_med":"PZA ","prec_prod":1062.60000000,"prec_prod3":1024.10000000,"porcenieps":0.00,"prec_prod2":1062.60000000,"prec_prod4":893.20000000,"porceniva":0.00},{"cve_prod":"ASPM2 ","desc_prod":"ASP.JACTO PJ PLUS18LTS ","desc1":" ","uni_med":"PZA ","prec_prod":971.50000000,"prec_prod3":938.00000000,"porcenieps":0.00,"prec_prod2":958.10000000,"prec_prod4":804.00000000,"porceniva":0.00}]
```

esta es la peticion que hago desde android

```
private void makeRequest(){

    NetworkInfo network = this.conManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(network.isConnected()){

        String url = "http://192.168.0.6:8080/api/products/getproductsprices";
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                            makeTable(response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

         queue.add(stringRequest);



    }else{
        new AlertDialog
                .Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage("NO ESTAS CONECTADO, ES NECESARIO TENER ACCESO A INTERNET.")
                .show();
    }
}


private void makeTable(String json){



    try{
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);

    }catch(JSONException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

alguien puede ayudarme.. gracias

Comment: gracias ya lo cambie

Comment: porque serializas un datatable ? no tienes una clase, quizas la que defines en ProductsModel con propiedades, esa es la que debes serializar a json y no un datatable

Comment: copie y pegue el primer objecto del array donde se queja JSONException en un [validador](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) y me indica que tiene un formato incorrecto, o quizas solo sea por el blockquote de SO cuando se le dio formato.

Comment: seguro el validado marca incorrecto porque falta un "]" al final. solo puse una parte, estoy viendo que el objeto en algunos keys trae caracteres raros como "\nP", "\n", "\r" no se si eso tenga que ver

Comment: Leandro Tuttini la documentacion de newtonsoft dice que el metodo SerializeObject(Object) acepta un objeto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad no es un JsonArray valido , el error indica que no se tiene el contenedor de cierre que indica un Json Array, además tienes saltos de linea al parecer en la respuesta :

> Value [{"cve_prod":"ASPM1 ","descripcion":"ASP. JACTO PJH DE 20 LTS
>   ","activo":" ","umed":"PZA
>   ","l1":"956.34","l3":"956.34","l2":"921.69","l4":"893.20"},{"cve_prod":"ASPM2
>   ","descripcion":"ASP.JACTO PJ PLUS18LTS ","activo":" ","umed":"PZA
>   ","l1":"874.35","l3":"862.29","l2":"844.20","l4":"804.00"}

Te sugiero primeramente eliminar estos caracteres antes de procesar el contenido Json mediante una REGEX:

```
string respuesta = Regex.Replace(repuestaJSON, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
```

Comment: gracias efectivamente elimine los caracteres que me comentas y efectivamente funciono, pero la raiz del problema era el response del web service en lugar de retornar un string en mi webservice retorne un object, por que el string pone ademas " [{},{},{}] " comillas al principio y al final del json y el parser de android no lo parsea.gracias. slaudos

Comment: Excelente! @NovEskEduard , ok solo debe tener los contenedores [ ... ] para que sea un Json Array no comillas dobles.